# angularjs constant code lint

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, constants, lint

I'm using 02_jshint.js to code lint my Ionic project, everything goes well until I receive this error:

```
35:4 -> Missing semicolon. ->  })
```

and it's pointing to the last constant's bracket of my code:

```
angular.module('myApp.constants',['ionic'])

    .constant('A','2.1.4')
    .constant('B','1.1.3')

    .constant("c", {
          "d": "cost1",
          "e": "cost2",
          "f": "cost3"
     })
```

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid this warning or to correct the error, it's clear that the code is correct but I would like to build my project (it doesn't allow to do that if there are any errors).
Any advice?

Comment: why you can't put semicolon there?

Comment: lint it anywhere else and you'll get the same error because it is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [jshint documentation jshint.com/docs](http://jshint.com/docs/).

In case you know why you don't want to put a semicolon there (which would be a good practice) try to put some `ignore` directives around it:

A directive for telling JSHint to ignore a block of code.

```
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

Additionally, you can ignore a single line with a trailing comment:

```
ignoreThis(); // jshint ignore:line
```

Comment: and if I want to ignore completely in all the files? the docs are very very unclear

Answer (score 1):

`angular.module('myApp.constants',['ionic']).whatevergoeshere()` is a chained statement. In JavaScript you always should terminate statements using a semicolon.
I advice you not to switch this rule off but just add the semicolon.

> The semicolon (;) character is used to separate statements in JavaScript code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling

Answer (score 0):

you missed semicolon in the last.

```
angular.module('myApp.constants',['ionic'])
   .constant('A','2.1.4')
   .constant('B','1.1.3')
   .constant("c", {
         "d": "cost1",
         "e": "cost2",
         "f": "cost3"
      });
```

Comment: this comment is correct, the semicolon error message refers to the ";" missing at end of statement.